# Define A Nested GraphQL Object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, graphql

In Ruby I can define a GraphQL Object with fields

```
GraphqlObjectType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  field :metadata
end
```

But how can I create a multi level nested GraphQL object?

I'm unsure how to interpret the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/GraphQL/ObjectType) How is `types[PersonType]` defined?

I like to end up with a structure

```
metadata: {
    form_issues: {
        person: {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Where/how do I define the nested resolvers?

```
GraphqlObjectType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define(name: "GraphqlObjectType") do
  field :metadata, MetadataType
end

MetadataType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define(name: "MetadataType") do
  field :form_issues, FormIssuesType
end

FormIssuesType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define(name: "FormIssuesType") do
  field :person, PersonType
end

PersonType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define(name: "PersonType") do
  field :dob, GraphQL::STRING_TYPE
end

# do you define the leaf node resolver
def dob 
  '01/01/1999'
end

# or the root node resolver
def metadata 
  {
    metadata: {
      form_issues: {
        person: {
          dob: '01/01/1999'
        }
      }
    }
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  field :director, PersonType
>   field :cast, CastType
>   field :starring, types[PersonType] do
>     argument :limit, types.Int
>     resolve ->(object, args, ctx) {
>       stars = object.cast.stars
>       args[:limit] && stars = stars.limit(args[:limit])
>       stars
>     }
>    end
> ```

Assuming you have `PersonType` defined, `field :director, PersonType` refers to a single instance of that type. And `field :starring, types[PersonType]` means "an array of `PersonType`". This is just graphql-ruby's way of expressing this concept, similar to `!`, which means "required / non-null".

```
PersonType # => person, can be null.
!PersonType # non-null person.
types[PersonType] # array of people, can be null itself, the array. People inside can be null too.
!types[PersonType] # array can't be null, but can contain nulls.
!types[!PersonType] # array can't be null and can't contain nulls.
```

So your schema can look something like this:

```
field :metadata, MetadataType

# MetadataType
field :form_issues, FormIssuesType # why is this not an array, as the name suggests?
# field :form_issues, types[FormIssueType] # use this for an array

# FormIssuesType / FormIssueType
field :person, PersonType
```

Apply "non-null" modifier where appropriate.